# facebook App review details: pages_manage_posts

Tags: facebook, permissions, review

Not approved: pages_manage_posts

App verification comments
In order to approve permissions for you to use in an app, we must be able to test its functionality. If we require a user account to do this (as opposed to a Facebook login), please be sure to provide the applicable test login and password for our reviewers to use.
Learn more about submitting a review.
Reviewer's Note:
Hello Team,

We found that your instructions are insufficient or lacking for us to review and utilize the requested permission.

To resolve this issue, please consider including any applicable test instructions on your next submission.

Thanks.

I provided the account number and password of the test, and the reply from the auditor, I am very confused and do not know what it means, please help, thank you